# solr installed on 8983 and solrcloud with 2 nodes on ports 8984 and 7574

Tags: solr

I installed solr on port 8983 and created a core **mycore** and then installed solrcloud with 2 nodes on ports 8984 and 7574.

When I index sample xml from exampledocs on **mycore** port 8983 using below command

```
 java -Dc=mycore -jar post.jar C:\solr-6.4.0\example\exampledocs\solr.xml
```

I get error:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">130</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</str></lst><str name="msg">Exception writing document id 7be3295f-4f17-4e71-8c62-b1ca1331d524 to the index; possible analysis error: cannot change DocValues type from SORTED to SORTED_SET for field "id"</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update
```

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing Exception writing document id field.

```
cannot change DocValues type from SORTED to SORTED_SET for field "id"
```

check you schema file for `id` field and its definition, make sure it is of type solr.StrField

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

Comment: id fieldType definition ex: `<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />`